# How does glm::mat4 constructor works?

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

How does this line of code work?

`glm::mat4 trans = glm::mat4(1.0f);`

Why do i have to pass only one float and how does the matrix look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [OpenGL Mathematics (GLM) API documentation](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/index.html) is based on OpenGL Shading Language (GLSL) and refers to [The OpenGL Shading Language specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html#constructors).

> **5.4.2 Vector and Matrix Constructors**
>
> [...] If there is a single scalar parameter to a matrix constructor, it is used to initialize all the components on the matrix's diagonal, with the remaining components initialized to 0.0.

An [Identity matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix) can be initialized by the single parameter 1.0.
If you pass 0.0 as a single argument, all of the fields in the matrix are 0.0, which is rather useless.
The default constructor leaves the fields of the matrix uninitialized.

Generally a matrix (*m*) is used to transform a vector (v' = m * v). If all the fields of a matrix are 0.0, all the components the result vector (*v'*) are 0.0, too.